# Как сделать обновление переменной по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, tkinter, lambda

Есть функция `OpenWin1()`, которая открывает окно с настройками, куда ты вводишь координаты, размеры и тд (пока сделал только координаты). 
По нажатию создаётся в другом файле строки уже с настройками.

Всё работает, всё нормально, но переменные не обновляются, принимая текст по умолчанию (`pos Y`, `pos X`).

Надо сделать так, чтобы при нажатии кнопки **`"Update"`** переменная обновлялась.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import subprocess
import time
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('123')
root.geometry('400x600')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

font = ('intro.otf', 12)

def Insert(file_name, text_line, text_to_add):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
        text = read_file.readlines()
        text.insert(text_line, text_to_add+"\n")
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as write_file:
        for i in text:
            write_file.write(i)
    with open(r"game.py", 'r') as fp:
        for count, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass

def OpenWin1():
    Win1 = Tk()
    Win1.title('Setup gameobject')
    Win1.geometry('220x200')
    Win1.resizable(width=False,height=False)
    WB1 = Button(Win1,text='Add gameobject',command=lambda:Insert("game.py", 24, f'    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ({Xprint}, {Yprint}, 75, 75))'), font=font)
    WB1.place(y=10,x=40)
    #Yprint
    info_Tf = Entry(Win1)
    info_Tf.insert(END, 'Pos Y')
    info_Tf.place(y=120,x=40)
    #Xprint
    info_Tf2 = Entry(Win1)
    info_Tf2.insert(END, 'Pos X')
    info_Tf2.place(y=100,x=40)
    Yprint = info_Tf.get()
    Xprint = info_Tf2.get()
    Win1.mainloop()

btn1 = Button(root, text='Add Rect(Game Object)', command=lambda:OpenWin1())
btn1.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Мне нужно, чтобы написанное в полях для ввода записывалось в переменную. Так и происходит, но оно не обновляется, а записывается только 1 раз в начале.

ВАЖНО! Если вы хотите запустить этот код, создайте файл **game.py** в той же папке где и этот код.

Comment: Петя, пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему и лучше расскажите что вы хотите сделать.

Comment: *функция которую я предоставил в вопросе*
```btn1 = Button(root, text='Add Rect(Game Object)', command=lambda:OpenWin1())
btn1.place(x=0, y=0)```

Comment: ```def Insert(file_name, text_line, text_to_add):
    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
        text = read_file.readlines()
        text.insert(text_line, text_to_add+"\n")
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as write_file:
        for i in text:
            write_file.write(i)
    with open(r"game.py", 'r') as fp:
        for count, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass```
это функция Insert, что используется в OpenWin1

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы написанное в полях для ввода записывалось в переменную. Так и происходит, но оно не обновляется, а записывается только 1 раз в начале

Comment: Петя, вам нужно предоставить минимально-воспроизводимый пример. Cмотрите ссылку из первого комментария. Все изменения и дополнения надо публиковать в теле вопроса, а не в комментариях.

Comment: я всё исправил, спасибо

Comment: а помогать собираешься?

Comment: Петя, sorry, предоставленный вами код- не воспроизводимый. Скопируйте ваш код во вновь созданную папку и попробуйте его запустить.

Comment: теперь всё работает...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from tkinter import *


root = Tk()
root.title('123')
root.geometry('400x600')
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

font = ('intro.otf', 12)

# -----------------------------> vvvvvvv  vvvvvvvv <-------------------------
def Insert(file_name, text_line, info_Tf, info_Tf2):           # text_to_add):
    text_to_add = f'    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ({info_Tf2.get()}, '\
                  f'{info_Tf.get()}, 75, 75))'
    print(f'{text_to_add}\n')

    with open(file_name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as read_file:
        text = read_file.readlines()
        text.insert(text_line, text_to_add + "\n")
    with open(file_name, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as write_file:
        for i in text:
            write_file.write(i)
    with open(r"game.py", 'r') as fp:
        for count, line in enumerate(fp):
            pass

def openWin1():
    win1 = Tk()
    win1.title('Setup gameobject')
    win1.geometry('220x200')
    win1.resizable(width=False, height=False)

    wB1 = Button(win1,
        text='Add gameobject',
#        command=lambda: Insert("game.py", 24, 
#            f'    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE, ({Xprint}, {Yprint}, 75, 75))'), 
# -------------------------------------------> vvvvvvv  vvvvvvvv <---------------- # +++
        command=lambda: Insert("game.py", 24,  info_Tf, info_Tf2),
        font=font)
    wB1.place(y=10, x=40)

    #Yprint
    info_Tf = Entry(win1)
    info_Tf.insert(END, 'Pos Y')
    info_Tf.place(y=120, x=40)
    #Xprint
    info_Tf2 = Entry(win1)
    info_Tf2.insert(END, 'Pos X')
    info_Tf2.place(y=100, x=40)
    Yprint = info_Tf.get()
    Xprint = info_Tf2.get()
#?   Win1.mainloop()


btn1 = Button(root, text='Add Rect(Game Object)', 
#?   command=lambda: OpenWin1())
    command=openWin1)
btn1.place(x=0, y=0)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо, очень помог! дай Бог тебе здоровья

Comment: @Петя пожалуйста. Удачи вам.